# Issue parsing data from API using http

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data from a third-party API(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50`) and have hit the following error:

```
E/flutter (18902): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (18902): #0      ProfileProvider.fetchData.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:54:32)
E/flutter (18902): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:311:23)
E/flutter (18902): #2      ProfileProvider.fetchData.<anonymous closure> (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:52:13)
E/flutter (18902): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter (18902): #4      ProfileProvider.fetchData (package:profile_app/provider/data.dart:51:19)
E/flutter (18902): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18902):
```

The lines where the errors occur are commented on my code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';

class Profile {
  final String userName;
  final String name;
  final String emailId;
  final int timePeriod;
  final int age;
  final String nationality;
  final String number;
  final int streetNumber;
  final String streetName;
  final String city;
  final String country;
  final int postCode;
  final String picture;

  Profile({
    required this.userName,
    required this.name,
    required this.emailId,
    required this.timePeriod,
    required this.age,
    required this.nationality,
    required this.number,
    required this.streetNumber,
    required this.streetName,
    required this.city,
    required this.country,
    required this.postCode,
    required this.picture
  });
}

class ProfileProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Profile> _data = {};

  Map<String, Profile> get data {
    return {..._data};
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(extractedData);
    Map<String, Profile> map = {};
    extractedData.forEach((key, value) =>           //51:19
        map.putIfAbsent(key, () =>                  //52:13
            Profile(
                userName: value['results'].login.username,  //54:32
                name: value['results'].name.first,
                emailId: value['results'].email,
                timePeriod: value['results'].registered.age,
                age: value['results'].dob.age,
                nationality: value['results'].nat,
                number: value['results'].cell,
                streetNumber: value['results'].location.street.number,
                streetName: value['results'].location.street.name,
                city: value['results'].location.city,
                country: value['results'].location.country,
                postCode: value['results'].location.postcode,
                picture: value['results'].picture.large
            )
        )
    );
    _data = map;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Initially, I thought it was owing to me not correctly defining the data types of the following values: `postCode` and `timePeriod` which were both defined as integers in the JSON response. But correcting those didn't help either. The API call seems to work correctly as it doesn't hesitate to send the response which is as below:

```
    {
"results": [
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "title": "Mr",
      "first": "André",
      "last": "Brunner"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": {
    "number": 7771,
    "name": "Marktplatz"
  },
  "city": "Hatzfeld (Eder)",
  "state": "Bayern",
  "country": "Germany",
  "postcode": 39781,
  "coordinates": {
    "latitude": "-44.0823",
    "longitude": "-161.4976"
  },
  "timezone": {
    "offset": "+8:00",
    "description": "Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong"
  }
},
  "email": "andre.brunner@example.com",
  "login": {
    "uuid": "01dca515-c167-4eeb-a217-60e5178010c8",
    "username": "bigladybug476",
    "password": "buck",
    "salt": "WhBB53R6",
    "md5": "f0594b35b2b2baf0c434546e64f0fa05",
    "sha1": "db3586cac4b75d2d0c31ad5b6af6061b07aa1b60",
    "sha256": "a7225266f739056b352ce001bd76746c60f6e1f0c9955fc983bee3c9f949d8e9"
},
  "dob": {
    "date": "1946-11-28T06:55:28.967Z",
    "age": 75
},
  "registered": {
    "date": "2018-05-26T04:04:45.356Z",
    "age": 3
},
  "phone": "0145-0007517",
  "cell": "0170-7712395",
  "id": {
    "name": "",
    "value": null
},
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/31.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/31.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/31.jpg"
},
"nat": "DE"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to explain what the problem is, because the code is a bit confusing.

First; you have this line:

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
```

So let's remember that extractedData is a `Map<String, dynamic>` which contains the json response.

So then:

```
extractedData.forEach((key, value) => ...
```

That is the interesting part, for each key in your JSON response, you are running some code with the key and the value. But here is where it gets confusing because the response that you posted is definitely wrong, it is not valid JSON, so I can't tell you exactly how this code will run, but I can tell you one thing:

**The first time that code runs, the key will be equal to 'results' and value will be a list with a bunch of objects**

That is because 'results' is the first key in the JSON response.

So when you do this:

```
userName: value['results'].login.username,
```

value is a list, but you are trying to access a key as if it was a map, so you get an error.

I'm not sure what the solution is because I don't know what you expected this code to do.

**There is also another error in your code**

You can't access a map's values through the dot operator, you need to use `[]`, so even if you properly read `value['results']` calling `.login` will throw an error

so instead of `value['results'].login.username` it should be `value['results']['login']['username']`

Comment: I think I got you at the point that you've highlighted. I was actually getting a key to behave like a value when what I needed to do was extract the values off of that key i.e results in this case. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Can you please suggest what needs to be done here if I were to extract the values off the results key?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to happen, I can give you an idea, but only you know what the map variable should have as it's keys, because I don't understand it. Here is how I would have done it: `final results = (extractedData['results'] as List<dynamic>).map((value) => Profile(userName: value['login']['username'] ... )).toList()`, which will make a list of Profiles

Comment: The basic idea is to store all that JSON data in the _data variable in the exact same way as it looks when you check the data on the browser. Is it Ok to if I asked you to make the necessary changes to my code above?

Comment: The problem is that `_data` is a map of `<String, Profile>`, but your data is best case scenario `<String, List<Profile>>`, assuming you change the type of `_data`, you can just do this: `_data = {'results': (extractedData['results'] as List<dynamic>).map((value) => Profile(userName: value['login']['username'] ... )).toList()}`

Comment: The above is assuming your JSON response is of the shape `{'results': [...]}`, if there is more data in your response, it will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the package `json_serializable` to help you create the method to convert from JSON and to convert to JSON for your model classes.

In your case, you would have the method:

```
factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Profile(
      username: json['username'] as String? ?? '',
      name: json['name'] as String? ?? '',
      emailId: json['emailId'] as String? ?? '',
      ...
    );
```

Then in your `fetchData()` method you can do this:

```
final jsonMap = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
final profile = Profile.fromJson(jsonMap);
```

Also you can use this link:
[JSON to Dart Converter](https://www.webinovers.com/web-tools/json-to-dart-convertor)
to help you generate the Dart class from your JSON response string.